# Variable visibility issue with Pandas and IPython

Tags: python, pandas, namespaces, ipython

I get a NameError exception when I try to filter DataFrame by selected index values (inside IPython session). You can see that `valid` is `numpy.array` while `lab` is a `pandas.DataFrame` object. Both of them are initialized and accessible. However I cannot put them together. Here is the error:

```
In [51]: valid
Out[51]: 
array([38661, 44593, 38705, 38918, 38727, 38757, 38751, 38777, 38787,
       ...,    
       45328, 45337, 43645, 43694, 43701])

In [52]: lab
Out[52]: 
         0
39333   -1
39173   -1
42756   -1
39633   -1
38661   -1
44801   81
...    ...
39379   -1
39742   -1
44765  108
44279   -1
40584   -1
41047   -1
41833   98

[3299 rows x 1 columns]

In [53]: lab[lab.index.map(lambda x: x in valid)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/vitaly/progs/vnii_gochs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 lab[lab.index.map(lambda x: x in valid)]

/home/vitaly/progs/vnii_gochs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in map(self, mapper)
   1558 
   1559     def map(self, mapper):
-> 1560         return self._arrmap(self.values, mapper)
   1561 
   1562     def isin(self, values, level=None):

/home/vitaly/progs/vnii_gochs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/algos.so in pandas.algos.arrmap_int64 (pandas/algos.c:78469)()

/home/vitaly/progs/vnii_gochs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 lab[lab.index.map(lambda x: x in valid)]

NameError: global name 'valid' is not defined
```

What's wrong with this code?

**UPD:** [lab.pkl](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/cf3704a0) (pickle format), [valid.npy](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/a5c78493) (numpy binary format)

Comment: Can you add a minimal example we can run to reproduce your error?

Comment: @cel, I have posted links to files with object dumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear if you trying to add a new column to `lab`, or if you are trying to get values in the order specified in the `valid` array. To add a new column to `lab` you can do `lab['new'] = valid`. To get a Series object ordered according to the values in the `valid` array you can do `lab.loc[value]`. If you just want the raw numpy array do `lab.loc[value].values`

Comment: I wanted to get new DataFrame object consisting of the selected index values. In order to get the one I tried to

Comment: I wanted to get new DataFrame object consisting of the selected index values. In order to get the one I tried to select the rows with a desired values of index (see `valid` array). Recently I've succeeded with your second approach (making new column from index). However, the cause of the error and exception type are still unclear.